# How to make a search form work with multiple fields using PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Hi All,**
      I am trying to make a search form work with multiple fields. The user is free to fill whatever field he wishes and leave the others blank. The search box looks like this.

Search Box Image with result table at bottom:
[image]

I know how to make it work without PDO with old mysql code. 
PHP CODE FOR SEARCH IS :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     // define the list of fields
$fields = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'job', 'country', 'city');
$conditions = array();

        // loop through the defined fields
        foreach($fields as $field){
            // if the field is set and not empty
            if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
                // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
                $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]) . "%'";
            }
        }
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("php_test", $con) or die("ERROR");

        // builds the query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM people ";
        // if there are conditions defined
        if(count($conditions) > 0) {
            // append the conditions
            $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' OR ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
        }

      //  echo $query;
        $result = mysql_query($query);
  }
 ?>
```

**(Note: I have not included any validation but I will do it)**

It's working just fine but I wanted to do the same using PDO.

I know that if I do something like below code it will work in PDO :-

```
 $q = $_POST['q'];

        $search = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");

        $search->execute(array("%$q%"));
              foreach($search as $s) {
                echo $s['name'];
        }
```

But I am having a hard time figuring out how to do it multiple fields and use prepared statement. Even a hint in the right direction will be very very helpful.

Thank You All in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like you did before:

```
$fields = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'job', 'country', 'city');
$inputParameters = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    // don't forget to validate the fields values from $_POST
    if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $inputParameters[$field] = '%' . $_POST[$field] . '%';
    }
}

$where = implode(' OR ', array_map(function($item) {
    return "`$item` LIKE :$item";
}, array_keys($inputParameters)));

$search = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE $where");
$search->execute($inputParameters);

foreach ($search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I had to modify a bit but it worked. I had to modify this : if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
                    $inputParameters[$field] = '%' . $_POST[$field] . '%';
                }  - To -                                                                                                                if (isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != "") {
                    $inputParameters[$field] = '%' . $_POST[$field] . '%';
                }

Comment: Use empty.. I've updated the answer.. you should accept iy if helped

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
$q = $_POST['q'];
$query = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE ";

// loop over submitted input keywords
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $query .= $keyword . " LIKE ? ";
}

$sql=$db->prepare($query);

// loop over submitted input values array
foreach($values as $k => $value){
   $sql->bindParam($k+1, '%'.$value.'%');
}

$sql->execute ();
```